# TypeError: response.getMessage is not a function

Tags: grpc, grpc-web

I am trying to set-up the GRPC React.js client with Ruby server. I have tested the server with simple Ruby client and it worked so moved on and tried to implement it in my React app, but I get an error `TypeError: response.getMessage is not a function` when trying to get the message. I can see the requests correctly end up in the server and when I look at the `response` itself it looks like it holds the value I expect (`Hello`). What could be the problem?

```
# my_component.js
componentDidMount() {
    const request = new Point()
    request.setSensorId(1)
    request.setDays(7)

    this.client.getHistoricalData(request, {}, (err, response) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(
          `Unexpected error for sayHello: code = ${err.code}` +
            `, message = "${err.message}"`
        )
      } else {
        console.log(response)
        console.log(response.getMessage())
      }
    })
  }
```

```
# response
{
    "wrappers_": null,
    "arrayIndexOffset_": -1,
    "array": [
        "Hello"
    ],
    "pivot_": 1.7976931348623157e+308,
    "convertedPrimitiveFields_": {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the response variable is a JSON, you cannot call the method getMessage since the object does not have this method. To do so, you can access the values inside of the JSON with `json.attribute`.

For example, in your case, `response.pivot_` should work and return  `1.7976931348623157e+308` and to get the `Hello` message you can call `console.log(response.array[0])`.

As an alternative, you can create a method of getMessage, where you pass the response, and extract the message.

```
getMessage(json) {
  return json.array[0]
}
```

And, when calling,`console.log(getMessage(response))`, it should return `Hello`